# How to manage an overgrown .RData file?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have an .RData file that is 1.8GB. Is that normal? It takes forever to open a Project in R Studio now. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you save your workspace at the end of each session? I generally don't, preferring to read any required data in fresh at the start of each session, and I think a lot of R users would recommend the same. You'll have to check that you're not going to lose useful data before you delete anything though.

Comment: I'd rename the .RData file to something else, e.g. .RData_00. Start RStudio, and load the file. Trim out whatever you don't want. You'll probably want to make a cup of tea or coffee or something while the file loads. As @Marius says, saving your workspace after every session is not always the best choice for a default. I save only what I want to keep, in specific files.

Comment: Use `rm` on whatever you no longer need. In the Environment pane, RStudio will normally tell you if you have any particularly large objects, or you can check all the size of everything with `sort(sapply(ls(), object.size), decreasing = TRUE)` (use `head` if necessary).

Comment: `object.size()` does not work on `ls()` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the .rdata file solved the problem. Going forward I am very particular what I am saving to .rdata upon Exiting R.